# Getting the specific value in loading data from Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am fetching the entities from Core Data, but I can´t access the object values to assign a variable etc.

This is my code:

```
    @IBAction func loadItem(sender: UIButton) {

    let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Words")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


    do {
        let results:NSArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

        for res in results{

            print(res)
            print(res.word)

        }


    } catch {
        print("Unresolved error")
        abort()
    }


}
```

print(res) works fine and give me the object in the console:

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x7ff0095355f0> (entity: Words; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://0E645702-9493-4D1A-8D55-4482B7948054/Words/p1> ; data: {
image = <89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452 00000a6c 000006ec 08020000 009fcbb9 fc000001 18694343 50494343 2050726f 6669>;
word = test;
})
```

But how can I access for instance the "word" value? It only returns this error:

"ViewController.swift:36:23: Value of type 'Element' (aka 'AnyObject') has no member 'word'"

I´m trying to cast "res" to be a NSManagedObject, but I can´t seem to make it work.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options. Either use Key-Value Coding:

```
let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
for res in results {
    print(res)
    print(res.valueForKey("word"))
}
```

Or (better) use "Xcode->Editor->Create NSManagedObject subclass ...".
In Xcode 7 this will add two files "Words.swift" and "Words+CoreDataProperties.swift" to your project.

The first file
"Words.swift" defined the `Word` class (and you can extend the class
definition e.g. to add custom methods).

The second file "Words+CoreDataProperties.swift"
contains property definitions for all your Core Data properties,
for example:

```
extension Words {

    @NSManaged var word: String?
    // ...
}
```

And now you can cast the objects from the fetch request to the `Word` type and  access the properties directly:

```
let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Words]
for res in results {
    print(res)
    print(res.word)
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. :)

Comment: Hmm. It seems like I had to cast Res as Words. If I cast the array as array of Words the res variable still is Element. When I solved it doing this: let results:NSArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
            
            for res in results{
                let nyRes = res as! Words
                print(res)
                print(nyRes.word!)

            }
Do you know of way to fix it with the Words array like you proposed?

Comment: @Praise: My fault. The class name is (usually) identical to the entity name, which is "Words" in your case. Casting the results array to `[Words]` should work.

Comment: No problem. I understood what you meant. But as I wrote above; I could not get it to work with they array as res still seems to be "Element" and not a "Words"

Comment: @Praise: Sorry, I don't get it. Can you append your new code to the question?

Comment: @Praise: You did not copy my suggested code correctly :) `let results:NSArray = ...` should simply be `let results = ...`.

Comment: Ahh! My bad. :/ Awesome! Thank you.